# CANBus problem with STM32

Tags: stm32, can

I am working with CAN Bus on the Nucleo H743ZI2 (STM32), I have set up the times for a clock souce of 10 Mhz, and can baud rate of 1 Mbps. Everything seems to work correctly until the motor is turn on with its power  supply.

In the CAN net I have connected:

Devices :

Nucleo + transceiver
Teensy + transceiver
Motor NANOTEC CANopen
USBtin CAN2USB

When the motor is off I can send messages and see them on the CAN lines with no problem.

WHen the motor is on I can send messages from the teensy with no problems and I can see them on the oscilloscope and the usbtin.

But when I try to send messages with the motor on with the Nucleo board with a transceiver (the transceiver is another board of the same type as the one with the teensy) some frames are corrupted.

I saw them in the oscilloscope and I attach some images, do you have any idea how I can solve it ?

**TL;DR:**
Motor off - Nucleo CAN messages fine, teensy CAN messages fine.

Motor on  - Nucleo CAN messages bad, teensy CAN messages fine.

CHANNEL 1 IS CANtx STM32, CHANNEL 2 IS CANRx STM32, CHANNEL 3 is CANH ,   CHANNEL 4 is CANL of the oscilloscope, B1 is the protocol decoding of the oscilloscope.
Screenshots [image: STM43]

Comment: Did you connect CAN ground and did you use twisted pair cabling?

Comment: *"CHANNEL 4 is CANL of the **oscilloscope**"*...? Channel 3 and 4 are the CAN pins on the Teensy, right?

Comment: My gut tells me a failing transceiver. It can be seen where Tx is commanding the transceiver to "transmit" but what makes it out on the bus is noise. Then the Rx is idle too long and this looks like an error frame. Make sure that the power to the transceiver is stable.

Comment: @Codo my bad, meant that it is connected to that channel of the oscilloscope, so CANL is connected to that Channel. Channel 3 and 4 are the CAN pins on the Nucleo board (stm32).

Comment: @vini_i I will try that, thanks.